# Basic USB Endpoint0 configuration error ATmega32u2

Tags: microcontroller, usb, atmega, usb-device, debugging

I've been trying to make a simple custom usb device class for a project based on the Atmega32u2.  I have been trying to get a usb device enumerated, but I can't get endpoint 0 properly configured. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAx_2p2_Sfk&list=PLCGpd0Do5-I0LUuFImUlkj2RhoiMCFPhe&index=3,  for the ATmega32u4. From the datasheets it looks like there are only small changes in the hardware implementation of USB. I have been over the specs multiple times but I can't find the error. It appears as though endpoint 0 has to be activated before any packets are acknowledged, but I can't get it configured. Here's the datasheet: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATMEGA32U2.

From the datasheet I thought I could use the basic algorithm I have in code. But from my tests it looks like the datasheet is missing something about the setup routine. Everything seems to work except for the 'Configure USB interface' (second last item). When I run my code, it can't change any of the registers controlled by UENUM, or UENUM itself meaning I cannot configure endpoint 0. I think I am missing something before the configuration stage which will activate the registers for writing, but I haven't been able to figure it out for a few days now.
[image]
[image]

About my setup.  I currently only have 1 led for debugging.  I am using it to check whether or not bits are being set, in most cases if the bit is set, the led lights up. I know that the code never makes it to the General Interrupt, nor is it able to change any registers in the usb_init_endpoint funciton or unfreeze the clock.

```
#define CBI(adr, bit) (adr &= ~(1<<bit)) /* Clear bit in register */
#define SBI(adr, bit) (adr |= (1<<bit)) /* Set bit in register */

//USB General Interrupt
ISR(USB_GEN_vect){
    Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
    led.setBit();//doesn't work
    //Check for end of reset
    if(UDINT & (1 << EORSTI)){
        CBI(UDINT, EORSTI); //Clear end of reset interrupt
        //Init Endpoint 0
        usb_init_endpoint(0, Ep0_ty, Ep0_di, Ep0_si, Ep0_ba);
        SBI(UEIENX, RXSTPE); //Enable RX IRQ
    }
}

void usb_init(){
    
    //Configure PLL
    CBI(PLLCSR, 2); // For 8Mhz
    //SBI(PLLCSR, 2); // For 16Mhz

    //Enable PLL
    CBI(USBCON, FRZCLK); //Unfreeze the clock This won't clear bit in register
    SBI(PLLCSR, PLLE); //Enable PLL
    
    //Check PLL Lock
    while(!(PLLCSR & (1 << PLOCK)));

    //Enable USB Interface
    SBI(USBCON, USBE);
    if((USBCON & (1 << USBE))){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        //led.setBit();//works
    }
    
    //Configure USB Interface (Ep0)
    //-Also configured in the usb general interrupt 
    if(usb_init_endpoint(0, Ep0_ty, Ep0_di, Ep0_si, Ep0_ba)){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        led.setBit();//doesn't work
    }
    //Enable USB interrupts
    SBI(UDIEN, EORSTE);
    if((UDIEN & (1 << EORSTE))){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        //led.setBit();//works
    }

    //Attach USB Device
    CBI(UDCON, DETACH);
    if((UDCON & (1 << DETACH)) == 0){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        //led.setBit();//works
    }
}

// Type - UECFG0X  0-Control, 1-Isochronous, 2-Bulk, 3-Interrupt
// Dir -  UECFG0X  0-Out, 1-IN
// Size - UECFG1X  0-8 Bytes, 1-16, 2-32, 3-64 Bytes
// Bank - UECFG1X  0-1 Bank, 1-2 Banks 
uint8_t usb_init_endpoint(uint8_t epnum, uint8_t type, uint8_t direction, uint8_t size, uint8_t bank){
    // Select endpoint
    UENUM = epnum; //this wont actually change data in the register
    if(UENUM == 0){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        //led.setBit();//lights up but there is a bug
    }

    if((UERST & (1 << EPRST0)) == 0){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        //led.setBit(); //works
    }
    // Activate endpoint
    SBI(UECONX, EPEN); //this wont actually change data in the register
    if((UECONX/* & (1 << EPEN)*/)){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        led.setBit(); //doesn't work
    }
    // Set type and direction (not yet disabled feature?)
    UECFG0X = ((type << EPTYPE0) | (direction << EPDIR)); 
    // Set size and number of banks
    UECFG1X = ((size << EPSIZE0) | (bank << EPBK0));
    
    // Alloc endpoint
    SBI(UECFG1X, ALLOC);
    
    // Test current endpoint configuration
    if((UESTA0X & (1<<CFGOK))){
        Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
        led.setBit(); //doesn't work
    }
    return (UESTA0X & (1 << CFGOK));// >> CFGOK;
}

int main(void)
{
    Pin led = Pin(&PORTD, &DDRD, &PIND, 0);
    led.enableOutput();
    
    usb_init();
    sei();
    
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Edit: The frzclk bit won't clear either, which is probably why the other bits won't set.  In the datasheet it says that most of the USB registers can't be written to unless USB is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.  I actually had to enable the usb interface before I unfreeze the clock.  Looks like the datasheet was a bit misleading. Simply writing the bit to zero won't actually clear the register, I don't know why that is. It seems as though you don't need to call the setup endpoint 0 in usb_init, and is fine handled only in the ISR (it still enumerates without it).

```
USBCON = 1 << USBE; //Unfreeze the clock
```